# How to share/send large string in android share intent

Tags: android, android-intent, share, whatsapp

while sending/share text to whatsapp texts are truncating. I tried with below methods

method 1

`Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("whatsapp://send?text="" +MyData)`

mehtod 2

`Intent myIntent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);`

`myIntent.setType("text/plain");`

`myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, appName);`

`myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, myData);`

but both method string/text truncates in whatsapp, but same text sharing to email/gmail getting as expected in method 2

please help me.

Comment: Hi could you please help me

Comment: Same issue here. did u found any sol?